# How can I display documentation in Xcode via CodeSense?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autocomplete, javadoc, codesense

I am Java developer and would like to know how I can get the equivalent of a JavaDoc in Xcode when CodeSense is doing its auto-complete? If I hit the ESC button I can get a list of methods etc. but it does not show me the descriptions of what the methods do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite the same, but the close equivalent is Quick Help, accessible from the Help Menu.  It's a floating palette that dynamically shows a quick documentation for the method or class at your cursor position.

Comment: …and which is also accessible by Option-double-clicking a keyword in your code.

Comment: is there no way to automatically read documentation on the fly as the auto-sense pops up?

Comment: I don't believe there is.  To be honest, I find the method names themselves so descriptive that I don't find it necessary.  Even the longer abstract in quick help is often completely redundant with the method name.  E.g. NSString's `drawInRect:withAttributes:` has this in Quick Help: **Abstract:** Draws the receiver with the font and other display characteristics of the given attributes, within the specified rectangle in the currently focused NSView.

Answer (score 19):

I am new to xcode and mac. Bring your mouse over the method name and press **alt + left mouse click** to see help. To see full help press **alt + double mouse left click**.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the topic, on Xcode 13 you can invoke quick help by using:

```
⌥ (option) + mouse click
```

On any method, function, structure and etc...